# Sending my own $_POST data along with users

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, post

I've got a basic html form. When the user clicks 'submit', naturally the input data is stored in the $_POST array.

What if I wanted to include some of my own predefined data inside $_POST?

e.g. the user is updating the title of their post, when they click 'submit' I want to send their old title as well.

Any ideas? Sorry if I'm unclear...

Comment: you can include anything in the form you want. If you don't want the user to see it set it to hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not send it as a "hidden" input value?

```
<input type="hidden" name="old_value" value="something">
```

That way, it's not seen on the user end, but it's passed along as data that isn't changeable on their end (unless they open up a DOM inspector like Console or FF's developer tools).

Comment: That isn't very secure, as anyone can easily edit the info in there with firebug or javascript injection. Then again, you can also have someone using something like Tamper Data to edit get/post info.

Comment: From the sound of their request, it didn't need to be secure, but yes, you make a good point. Probably the best way is to not send it as POST data and save it as a session variable or something. If it needs to be secure, it shouldn't be sent as POST data anyway though...

Comment: Thanks, for what I'm doing that should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want the old title, shouldn't the old title be saved in the database or something else?

But for your question, you could add a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="old_title" value="<?php echo $old_value ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field in your form. The user won't see it but its contents get submitted.

```
<input type="hidden" name="h"/>
```

You can store the old title using javascript of jQuery

```
$("idOfThefield").val(oldtitle);
```

Hope this helps!